# c++ windows compiler slow output

Tags: python, c++, performance-testing, execution-time

i am using Dev-c++ version 5.11 and running a c++ code.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <time.h>

using namespace std ;

int main()
{
int start = clock();
for(int x = 0; x <=100000; x++)
{
cout << x << endl;
}
int stop = clock();
cout << endl;
cout << (stop-start)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
return 0;

}
```

It is taking 80sec - 75sec   on windows 8.1 pavilion g6 2.5Ghz but in python it executes in under 3 seconds how to decrease execution time in c++ code.

Python Code -- (Pycharm python ver.3)

```
 import time as t
 num = 100000
 start = t.time()
 for z in range(0, num):
     print(z)
 print(t.time() - start)
```

execution time - 2.95 seconds

Comment: And that's what you get for trying to learn C++ from random snippets from the internet. In other words, look up what language features do before using them. (Done properly, the program terminates in .18s on my system.)

Comment: Note that [`clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) doesn't return an `int`.

Comment: Also, are you doing the exact same thing in the Python script? Can you show it too?

Comment: Lastly, try removing that `endl` inside the loop. That causes the output to be flushed, and output in the Windows console is really slow. If you want to print a newline, print an actual newline (`'\n'`) instead.

Comment: @BaummitAugen How did you speed up the program? On my system it seems to be the console output takes all the time. The loop doesn't take much time at all.

Comment: The windows cmd console is about as fast as a teletype.

Comment: @Muscampester Use `'\n` instead of `endl`. Absolute numbers will vary between systems ofc, but not (much) between Python and C++ on the same system.

Comment: Windows console apparently isn't optimized for fast scrolling. See [Why is MSVC compiler weirdly slower than gcc on Linux and Xcode C++ compiler on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43041589/why-msvc-compiler-is-wiredly-slower-than-gcc-on-linux-and-xcode-c-compiler-on)

Comment: @BaummitAugen I could not replicate the result you mention with the change mentioned. When you state *done properly* did you mean *just use linux*?